# Gtk.RadioToolButton with icon and text?

Tags: python, gtk, radio-button, toggle, gnome

Here is my code for the toolbutton (in a toolbar):

```
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.overviewRadio = Gtk.RadioToolButton(stock_id=Gtk.STOCK_ABOUT)
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.overviewRadio.set_label("Overview")
# self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.overviewRadio.show_label() (No such function)
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.overviewRadio.connect("clicked", self.on_overviewRadio_clicked)
```

Here is a screenshot of the output:

[image: Screennshot]

As you can see, there is no label - how can I set the label to be revealed?

Here is my code, for those who are interested:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

###    Copyright (c) 2013 - Marco Scannadinari

###    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
###    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
###    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
###    (at your option) any later version.
###
###    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
###    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
###    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
###    GNU General Public License for more details.
###
###    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
###    along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

# gcustomiser - A visual customiser for the GNOME desktop using GTK+.

from gi.repository import Gtk
import sys

class gcustomiser:
    def __init__(self):
        ## Main window
        self.mainWindow = Gtk.Window(Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL)
        self.mainWindow.set_size_request(512, -1)
        self.mainWindow.set_resizable(False)
        self.mainWindow.set_title("GNOME Customiser")
        self.mainWindow.connect("destroy", self.on_mainWindow_destroy)

        ## Main box
        self.mainWindow.mainBox = Gtk.VBox(
            homogeneous = False,
            spacing = 8)

        ## Toolbar
        self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar = Gtk.Toolbar()
        self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.get_style_context().add_class(Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_PRIMARY_TOOLBAR)
        self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.set_style(Gtk.ToolbarStyle.BOTH)

        ## Left toolbar separator
        self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.leftSeparator = Gtk.SeparatorToolItem(draw = False)
        self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.leftSeparator.set_expand(True)

        ## Overview toggle button
        self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.overviewRadio = Gtk.RadioToolButton(Gtk.STOCK_ABOUT)
        self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.overviewRadio.set_is_important(True)
        self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.overviewRadio.set_label("Overview")
        self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.overviewRadio.connect("clicked", self.on_overviewRadio_clicked)

        ## Basic settings toggle button
        self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.basicRadio = Gtk.RadioToolButton(label = "Overview")
        self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.basicRadio.set_label("Overview")
        a = self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.basicRadio.get_label()
        print(a)
        ## Right toolbar separator
        self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.rightSeparator = Gtk.SeparatorToolItem(
            draw = False)
        self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.rightSeparator.set_expand(True)

        ## Add everything to self.mainWindow
        self.mainWindow.add(self.mainWindow.mainBox)

        self.mainWindow.mainBox.pack_start(
            self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar,
            expand = False,
            fill = True,
            padding = 0)

        self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.add(self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.leftSeparator)
        self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.add(self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.overviewRadio)
        self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.add(self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.rightSeparator)

    def on_mainWindow_destroy(self, *args):
        print("destroy: mainWindow")
        print("\nGoodbye.\n")

        Gtk.main_quit()

        sys.exit()

    def on_overviewRadio_clicked(self, *args):
        print("clicked: mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.overviewRadio")

    def show_all(self):
        self.mainWindow.show_all()

window = gcustomiser()
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that **I did not set a toolbar style**. To do this, I should use:

```
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.set_style(Gtk.ToolbarStyle.*)
```

If I wanted the label to be shown to the side of the icon, rather than below it, I need to make the radiobutton important:

```
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.set_style(Gtk.ToolbarStyle.BOTH_HORIZ)
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.overviewRadio.set_is_important(True)
```

For a list of `Gtk.ToolbarStyle`s, use `dir(Gtk.ToolbarStyle)` in the Python interpreter, or go to [this page](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/gtk-constants.html#gtk-toolbar-style-constants).

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
self.mainWindow.mainBox.mainToolbar.overviewRadio.show_all()
```

Although, you might want to consider:

```
self.mainWindow.show_all()
```

that will show every widget in mainWindow().  Usually is used after you have defined the main UI and want to make all the widgets visible.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show all of my code - I did run *.show_all(), but the label is still not shown.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to use the **Glade** interface editor and accomplish what you want to do a very easy way. The label of a **ToolButton** is a propiety which is visible by default, whenever the **widget** has the label label mean it has to display text below the icon, and even then we should not give any further that **show_label**, **show_label** not function defined for `gtk.RadioToolButton`.
Moreover I suggest that you check these links you leave here you might be useful

> http://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.RadioToolButton.html.content.tpl%20
>   http://nullege.com/codes/search/gtk.RadioToolButton.set_label
>   http://pascal.rigaud4.free.fr/Programmation/GTK/GTKMMDoc/GTKMM/www.gtkmm.org/docs/gtkmm-2.4/docs/reference/html/classGtk_1_1RadioToolButton.html

Comment: See my answer for the solution I just found out.